# Access k2 extra field from Flexi Code module

Tags: php, module, k2, variable

I am using the Flexi Code module to display some php in a k2 page.
This k2 page has a RoomID as extra field.

How can I access it as a variable inside Flexi Code?

Comment: I think that the only way to access it is to query db for this room id (using item id from URL). I do not know K2 tables so I am just commenting not providing the complete answer.

Comment: Well let's just say that I have a variable on my article detail template and I want to access it on the module as well, how is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible.